# Sort a datagridview column displaying DateTime objects

Tags: c#, winforms, datetime, columnsorting

I have a `DataGridView` with several columns, 1 of which is displaying employee birthdays as a `DateTime` like this:  `dateStyle.Format = "MMM-dd";` (Ex: `Jan-01` for January 1st). I would like to enable the user to be able to click on the header of this column in order to sort by date. I don't mind changing the `dateStyle` format as long as it is sorted chronologically. Any help would be appreciated. The program is in C# but for my other columns I am using a switch case like this:

```
private void dataGridView1_ColumnHeaderMouseClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)

 {

        switch(e.ColumnIndex - 1)
            {
            case #columnNumber:
            myList = myList.OrderBy(d => d.FirstName).ToList();
            break;
            }
  }
```

Comment: Have you tried doing exactly the same thing?

Comment: Yes. I put a breakpoint on the line that does that and when I clicked the header, it did not stop on it.

Comment: So put a breakpoint at the beginning of the event handler, and single-step... but I would first want to know whether it sorted, and whether the sort was by date (correct) or by alphabetizing the string version of the date.

Comment: I took it line by line and it jumped over the entire switch statement for columns displaying DateTime. I still havn't been able to sort. T

Comment: Check whether column index is what you expect?

Comment: @TatianaLaurent try to create custom class for `System.Collections.IComparer` and assign it to `DataGridView1.Sort` method. check this [tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wstxtkxs(v=vs.110).aspx)